# Is it possible to have a figure on one half and maths on the other, encapsulated by the same figure box?

Tags: floats, equations

This might not be possible but I am trying to force a picture and a set of maths equations deriving a concept that the picture helps to explain next to each other inside the same box with the same caption underneath as can be seen below. (Blue box representative of the picture and the (Maths equations here) where I would like the set of equations to go. The caption would be underneath both the picture and the equations across both columns.[image]

I have tried a couple of things including splitting that page into twocolumns but that doesn't work.

I have also tried

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Pic1}
        \caption{Picture 1}
        \label{fig:1}
     \end{subfigure}

    \begin{equation}
        y=mx+c
    \end{equation}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

but it doesn't quite work and puts the maths below the picture. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Should the equation also get a number?

Comment: Yes preferably, so it can be referred to from the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the following is what you're looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
     \end{minipage}%
     \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
         \begin{equation}
            y=mx+c
        \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```